# Pandas get_dummies to output dtype integer/bool instead of float

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know if could ask the get_dummies function in pandas to output the dummies dataframe with a dtype lighter than the default float64.

So, for a sample dataframe with categorical columns:

```
In []: df = pd.DataFrame([(blue,wood),(blue,metal),(red,wood)],
                         columns=['C1','C2'])
In []: df
Out[]:
    C1      C2
0   blue    wood
1   blue    metal
2   red     wood
```

after getting the dummies, it looks like:

```
In []: df = pd.get_dummies(df)
In []: df    
Out[]:
 C1_blue    C1_red  C2_metal    C2_wood
0   1   0   0   1
1   1   0   1   0
2   0   1   0   1
```

which is perfectly fine. However, by default the 1's and 0's are float64:

```
In []: df.dtypes
Out[]: 
C1_blue     float64
C1_red      float64
C2_metal    float64
C2_wood     float64
dtype: object
```

I know I can change the dtype afterwards with `astype`:

```
In []: df = pd.get_dummies(df).astype(np.int8)
```

But I don't want to have the dataframe with floats in memory, because I am dealing with a big dataframe (from a csv of about ~5Gb). I would like to have the dummies directly as integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float issue is now solved. From pandas version 0.19, pd.get_dummies function returns dummy-encoded columns as small integers.

See: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#get-dummies-now-returns-integer-dtypes

Answer (score 2):

There is an open issue w.r.t. this, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8725

Comment: Thank you Jeff! Please let us know here once the issue is solved (if you remember it). By the way, the pd.Categorical does not solve this particular issue but it may help a lot in doing one-hot encoding.

Comment: Closed, implemented in 0.19.0