# transform string column of a pandas data frame into 0 1 vectors

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, one-hot-encoding

`LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder` works pretty good for numpy array, which transform string into `0,1` based vectors.

My question is, is there a neat API to convert a column of a pandas data frame into `0, 1` vectors? I showed my code and raw content of the pandas data frame `123.csv`, suppose I want to binary `0, 1` for columns `c_a`,`c_b`,`c_c`, each of the 3 columns are independent, I want to binary `0, 1` for the separately independent.

Code,

```
import pandas as pd
sample=pd.read_csv('123.csv', sep=',',header=None)
print sample.dtypes
```

123.csv content,

```
c_a,c_b,c_c,c_d
hello,python,pandas,1.2
hi,c++,vector,1.2
```

Label Encoder and OneHotEncoder examples for numpy,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

S = np.array(['b','a','c'])
le = LabelEncoder()
S = le.fit_transform(S)
print(S)
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
one_hot = ohe.fit_transform(S.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
print(one_hot)
which results in:

[1 0 2]

[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

**Edit 1**, tried `get_dummies`, and it seems results are `0.0` and `1.0` (seems `float`), is there a way to convert into integer directly?

```
   0_c_a  0_hello  0_hi  0_ho  1_c++  1_c_b  1_java  1_python  2_c_c  2_numpy  \
0    1.0      0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    1.0     0.0       0.0    1.0      0.0   
1    0.0      1.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0     0.0       1.0    0.0      0.0   
2    0.0      0.0   1.0   0.0    0.0    0.0     1.0       0.0    0.0      0.0   
3    0.0      0.0   0.0   1.0    1.0    0.0     0.0       0.0    0.0      1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `get_dummies`?

```
s = pd.Series(["a", "b", "a", "c"])
pd.get_dummies(s)
```

If you want `ints`:

```
pd.get_dummies(s).astype(np.uint8)
```

reference:

[Pandas get_dummies to output dtype integer/bool instead of float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468892/pandas-get-dummies-to-output-dtype-integer-bool-instead-of-float)

Comment: Thanks HYRY, tried `get_dummies`, and it seems results are `0.0` and `1.0` (seems `float`), is there a way to convert into integer directly? You can see my post update Edit 1 part for my trial results.

Comment: Thanks HYRY for the patience to provide help, mark your reply as answer, have a good weekend.